# magento 1.9.3 is not sending email after invoice created but yes order email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, invoice

magento 1.9.3 is not sending email after invoice created but yes order email.
I am also using pdf-invoice plus extension which used to send the invoice to pdf with order email but invoice email not sending to the customer.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick solution is:**

override the below path in your module or local folder 
& try the below code

Go to the following location:

**Copy this file**

> /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php

**Create the path and copy the file here**

> /app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php

**around Change Line 407**

```
if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {
```

**To:**

```
if (!($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue)) {
```